# How should I write a resolver while using apollo graphql server backed by neo4j database?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I am using neo4j dB and I have set up apollo graphql server (using graphql-server-express). Lets say my schema has 3 types namely "Country", "State" and "People" where 1 country can have multiple states and 1 state can have multiple people.

//Sample **schema.js**

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

import resolvers from './resolvers';

 const typeDefs = `
 type Country {
   id: Int! 
   name: String
   state: [State]
   people: [People]

  }

 type State {
     id: Int!
     name: String
     countryID: CountryID
     people: [People]

   }

   type People {
     id: Int!
     name: String
     SSN: String
     stateid:StateID
     countryid:CountryID
    }


    type Query {
      Countries: [Country]
      States: [State]
      Peoples: [People]

      }

    schema {
     query: Query

    }
   `;

   export default makeExecutableSchema({
      typeDefs: typeDefs,
      resolvers,
    });
```

**So, how should I write my resolver function in resolver.js file such that it would help me to fetch the data properly from any of the above types ?**

I tried to use the following query in resolver.js file (to query the Neo4j database using Cypher query language), but got the type error and i am unable to fix it.

//Sample resolver.js file.

```
let neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
let driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", 
  "******"));

 const resolver = {
  Query: {
     Countries(_, params) {
     let session = driver.session();
    let query = "MATCH (country:Country)  RETURN country;"
    return session.run(query, params)
      .then( result => { return result.records.map(record => { return 
      record.get("country").properties })})
    },
 },

 State:{
   state(State) {
    let session = driver.session(),
       params = {countryid: Country.id},
       query = `
        MATCH (s:State-[:PRESENT]->(c:Country)
        WHERE s.countryid = $countryid
        RETURN s;
       `
       return session.run(query, params)
         .then( result => { return result.records.map(record => { return 
     record.get("state").properties })})
      },
    },
  };

export default resolver;
```

Comment: What was the actual error you got and did you get it fixed?

Comment: yeah, the error was due to the case sensitivity on one of the above query resolver function. Although going through the following link, I learned a lot ! https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-a-simple-graphql-server-with-neo4j